# How do you log out winston the same way console.log does for objects and arrays while also keeping color formatting

Tags: winston

I currently have this configuration for my Winston logger:

```
const logLevel = 'info';
const logFormat = format.printf(function(info) {
    let output = `${info.level}: ${JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 4)}\n`;
    if(info.metadata) {
        delete info.metadata.dd;
        delete info.metadata.timestamp;
        if(Object.keys(info.metadata).length) {
            output += util.format('%o', info.metadata);
        }
    }
    return output;
});
const Logger = createLogger({
    level: logLevel,
    exitOnError: false,
    format: json(),
    transports: [
        new transports.Console({
            format: combine(timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }), format.metadata(), json(), errorsFormat, format.colorize(), format.simple(), splat(), logFormat),
        })
    ],
});
```

Which get's the logging pretty close to what I want, the only issue now is that arrays and objects are not colorized, for example take a look at the screenshots from this code:

```
console.log({data: 'testing'});
Logger.info(`Test out object logging`, {data: 'testing'});

console.log({
    name: 'Bill',
    age: 38,
    occupation: 'Dog Trainer'
})
Logger.info('Details', {
    name: 'Bill',
    age: 38,
    occupation: 'Dog Trainer'
})
```

[image: Console log vs winston]

Is there anyway to retain the color formatting in Winston when logging out to console? It makes the logs much easier to read when working in a local dev setup.